# How i do for work with objects with composition

Tags: c#

my name is aderson and in this moment i have something question about composition referents to performance.  In this model
i have a simple **userbase** and **departmentbase**. The userbase have a property of type deparmentbase and departmentbase have a list property of type departmentbase.
**When i have a instance of userbase in this moment load information about department but then DepartmentBase load information about Departments too!!!.**

Now, when i have a list of userbase for all user the process load again for all users, this is a good practise or what is the better form?

[alt text http://img146.imageshack.us/img146/3949/diagram.jpg](http://img146.imageshack.us/img146/3949/diagram.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it is a better (or even applicable) approach, but I sometimes make brief versions of objects that I use for references from other objects. The breif version acts as a base class for the full version of the object, and will typically contain the information that would be visible in a listing of such objects. It will often not contain lists of other objects, and any references to other classes will usually refer to the brief version of that class. This eliminates some unnecessary data loading, as well as some cases of circular references. Example:

```
public class DepartmentBrief
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Department : DepartmentBrief
{
    public Department()
    {
        Departments = new List<DepartmentBrief>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<DepartmentBrief> Departments { get; private set; }
}
public class UserBase
{
    public DepartmentBrief Department { get; set; }   
}
```

One difference between this approach and having full object references paired with lazy loading is that you will need to explicitly load extra data when it is needed. If you have a `UserBase` instance, and you need the department list from the `Department` of that `UserBase`, you will need to write some code to fetch the `Department` object that the `DepartmentBrief` object in `UserBase` is identifying. This could be considered a downside, but I personally like the fact that it will be clear when looking at the code exactly when it is going to hit the data store.

Comment: If you are accessing an instance of Department through its base class (DepartmentBrief), it is still the Department that is in memory. So in the moment when you need to access the list, you have to cast first (which doesn't make any sense). Using an interface (or a base class) is ok, but if a list of Departments is something that each department has, then it should be included in that interface. I don't see how casting can make any difference in performance.

Comment: @Groo: The point is that when populating UserBase, you do not assign a Department instance to it, but a DepartmentBase instance; there is no Department in memory. If you want the Deparment, you pick information from DepartmentBase, and fetch a Department instance from the data store.

Comment: Got it. DepartmentBrief only exist to have an ID to use for reference to the data store (correct me if I'm wrong). But wouldn't lazy init, or a proxy with the same interface which would do the job, be a better solution? This way you are changing you model design with performance in mind - which is something that should only be of secondary consideration. What I mean is - if you know what your interface should look like, why change it? You can easily add lazy init to any property later.

Comment: @Groo: you have valid points (hence my note around lazy loading in my answer); exposing the full interface with lazy loading mechanisms is another way to do it. It it is better or worse, I don't know. I personally like "stupid" models, and explicitly populating them when I need it. Just a clarification: DepartmentBase will indeed have more information than just an ID; as mentioned in my answer, it will contain basic information such as Name, Location or whatever may be relevant; brief information that can be displayed to the user to make it recognizable.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, if you need all the department data directly after loading the user list, then this is the best approach. If you don't need it immediately, you better use *[lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading)* for the department data. This means you postpone the loading of the department data until an explicit method (or property) has been called.

Comment: Thanks fretje I don't know that.